# MS Access 2019 is showing icons that were used in Office 2003

Tags: ms-access

I created a fresh ms access database using Access 2019. At some point, I realized that **MS Access was using icons that look like they are from the Office 2003 version when i insert new buttons.** Note: this happens with or without using the wizard.

I suspect the strange behavior might have something to do with me having imported data (tables only!) from a very old database that was designed in Access 2003.

As I have already invested substantial amounts of work, I can not start over, so I attempted to load all objects into a fresh access 2019 file. The old icons remained! However, in other databases that I open, the correct 2019 icon versions are loaded. Thus the icons are tied to the file.

**Can the icon set that an MS Access File references be changed? If so, how?**

Comment: File >> Options >> Current Database >> Use windows-themed controls on forms. Make sure it's checked.

Comment: Windows Themed controls is checked. Icons still looking like 2003.

Comment: There's another option below that, *Picture Property Storage Format*. The 1st option should be selected (preserve source image format). Any existing icons will have to be inserted again (they don't update automatically).

Comment: Great idea to look at that one. I hadn't thought of that option. Saddly, it is already set to the correct option. I've been exploring the button control itself. Switching it back and forth to windows-theme. It has not effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite having been stuck with the problem for several days I have now managed to solve it almost immediately after posting my question.

When I now create new buttons using the wizard I get the Office 2019 symbol set again.

What exactly triggered the correct icon set to reappear I can not say for certain, but **I suspect it is due to having changed one of the CurrentDatabase settings as suggested by @Kostas K.** To be clear: I have had the correct settings consistently, but in order to see what would happen, I deactivated them and then reactivated them.

I hope someone else that has the problem is able to benefit from this.